# nav bar is not creating dynamically

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

in my android app i m using nav bar which dynamically creating but it is not creating properly
please help me out what the mistake i did it

if i remove li tag thn it is coming but not in proper way

In one.xml:-

```
<cat>
  <id>1</id>
</cat>
<cat>
  <id>ATTR11</id>
</cat>
```

In JQuery:-

```
var a2 = "";
var a1 = "";
var reg = new RegExp('^[0-9]+$');
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "one.html",
  contentType: "text/xml",
  dataType: "xml",
  data: "",
  success: function (xml) {
    $(xml).find("cat").each(function () {
        var id = $(this).find('id').text();
        if (id.match(reg) !== null) {
            a2 = a2 + '<a href="#">' + id + '</a>';

        } else {
            a1 = a1 + '<li><a href="#">' + id + '</a></li>';

        }
        $("#xyz").append(a2).trigger('create');
        $("#abc").append(a1).trigger('create');
    }
    });
```

In HTML5:-

```
<div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top" >
  <ul id="abc"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: after you append navbars, call this `$('[data-role=page]').trigger('pagecreate');` and remove `.trigger('create')` in your code above.

Comment: @Omar its not working

Comment: well, you need to append a fresh navbar and enhance it using `.navbar()` http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/PH3fj/